# Chrome Extension chrome.action.onClick breaking chrome.runtime.onMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension using React. I am having an issue converting the extension from using the new tab page to an options page. This is a work project, so I didn't have an option other than a chrome extension.

I want to open the options page when the extension button is clicked on in the tool bar. Which is the first two snippets below. This works fine on its own.

However, I also want to add a message listener to the page. So I added that as well which is in the 3rd snippet. This sends all messages to a "router" and on it's own it also works perfectly.

The problem is that when I add both these functions to the background script file, the background never fires at all.

Can someone please help me figure this issue out?

Thanks in advance.
(code below)

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((t)=>{
    // execScript()
    console.log('working')
    execScriptOpts(t)
   
})
```

```js
async function execScriptOpts(tb: chrome.tabs.Tab){
    
    const currTabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});
    const exists = currTabs.find(t=>{
        return t.url.startsWith('chrome-extension://jpgfkhiojdbiiccbodijilibhjdiophi/options.html?page=home')
    });
    if(exists==null){
        const tab = await chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "chrome-extension://jpgfkhiojdbiiccbodijilibhjdiophi/options.html?page=home"
        });
        const newWindow = await chrome.windows.create({
            focused: true,
            state: 'maximized',
            tabId: tab.id
        },)

    }
    else{
        const windowId = `${exists.windowId}`
        const tabId = exists.id;
        const newWindow = await chrome.windows.create({
            focused: true,
            state: 'maximized',
            tabId: tabId
        },)

    }

}
```

```js
     chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req , sender, sendResponse) => {

        const {route, data} = req as IncomingReq;
        const request: RequestData = {route, data, sender, sendResponse}

        router(request);
        
        return true;
    })
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you confirmed that neither listener gets triggered at all? Have you looked at the inspect view for the service worker / background script to see if any errors are output?

Comment: `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener` isn't indented, but `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` is. Are you calling `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`from inside another function?

Comment: To state the obvious, your posted code is fine, assuming you compile it to plain JS, so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I've done all the debugging I could think of. The code I posted had about a 1000 console logs commented out. The service worker inspect doesn't show anything at all. The inspect tool when I open the option page by right clicking the Ext icon  and inspect it says that the connection can't be established.

Comment: Also Thomas, yes it was removed from inside the function when I made the example, but that is because I tried it in many different places. So I tried the message listener being called by the action, and the action calling the message and both completely separate.

Comment: Also in case it is relevant, every other chrome calls I make, for example "onLoad" all work perfectly. Just the two of these combined don't work.